# Как явно задать тип для значения NULL в SELECT?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, union

Eсть таблица со столбцами `COL_1 number, COL_2 number`.

Запрос целиком:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_1
```

И есть представление:

```
CREATE VIEW V1 AS
    SELECT NULL AS COL_1, TABLE_2.COL AS COL_2 FROM TABLE_2
```

Хочу их объединить:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_1
union all
SELECT * FROM V1
```

И получаю ошибку - выражения не соответствуют друг другу, ожидалось `NULL`, в представлении имеет тип `varchar2`. Но я не просил его быть текстовым.

Как явно задать тип?

Comment: а можно пример данных, на которых вы это выловили и саму ошибку.
Я попробовал написать:
`select null as n from dual
union all
select 12 from dual`  и никаких проблем не возникло

Comment: в крайнем случае можно еще явно написать `to_number`

Comment: "И вот он ругается, ... мол NULL в представлении типа varchar2" - кто ругается, как ругается?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Надо столбцы привести к одному типу. Например для:

```
create table table_1 (col_1 number(10), col_2 number);
create table table_2 (col number);
```

будет так:

```
CREATE VIEW V1 AS
SELECT CAST (NULL AS number(10)) AS COL_1, TABLE_2.COL AS COL_2 FROM TABLE_2
;
```

Функция `CAST` сконвертирует `NULL`, по умолчанию `VARCHAR2(0)`, в тип данных, указанный во втором операнде.

Тот же результат возможно также достигнуть функцией `to_number(null)`, но только если нет необходимости ограничения по длине (т.н. *non-constrained type*). То есть, например:

```
cast (null as number(10)) ... -- user_tab_cols.data_precision=10     
to_number (null) ...          -- user_tab_cols.data_precision=null
```

Подробнее в [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions024.htm#SQLRF00613).

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать не cast, а просто To_Number:

```
with tab as (
    select 1 as Col_1, 2 as Col_2 from Dual union all
    select 3, 4 from Dual union all
    select 5, 6 from Dual union all
    select 6, 8 from Dual union all
    select 7, 10 from Dual)
select Col_1, Col_2 from tab     
union all
select To_Number(null) as Col_1, Col_2 from tab
```

Comment: Не заметил, про To_Number уже писали.

Comment: Писали в комментарии, а не в ответе, что допускается.  Поменяйте селекты местами, чтобы было как вопросе.

Comment: Исправил. Я написал так, потому что когда я столкнулся первый раз с похожей проблемой, был именно не определен тип столбца в первом запросе.